# How to get unique JSONObject data from list of JSONObject by comparing specific key value?

Tags: java

I have like,

```
List<JSONObject> jsonObjectList =[
      {id: "aaa",key2: "bbb",key3="eee"},
      {id: "aaa",key2: "bbb",key3="fff"},
      {id: "aab",key2: "ccc",key3="eee"}
    ]
```

I need jsonObjectList unique value comparing by id value in java.

**I tried**

```
 List<JSONObject> distinctElements = jsonObjectList.stream()
                                .filter( distinctByKey(p -> p.getId()) )
                                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

**I want the following output for above example:**

```
distinctElements =[
  {id: "aaa",key2: "bbb",key3="fff"},
  {id: "aab",key2: "ccc",key3="eee"}
]
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Why needs code? My question is simple. I hope it is understandable..:-)

Comment: I mean where is your tried code, SO is not a code service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
List<JSONObject> distinctElements = jsonObjectList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(JSONObject::getId, Collectors.toList()))
    .values().stream()
    .map(list -> list.get(0))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also instantiate a `Set<>` implementation that allows you to specify a custom `keyExtractor`.

Comment: `[ERROR]   cannot find symbol`

`[ERROR]     symbol:   method getId()`

`[ERROR]     location: class net.minidev.json.JSONObject`

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Set as it prevents duplicate objects. And use some libray for JSON serialization, like Gson for example.

Comment: could you please give an example, based on my given example?